# SuperLearner Predict error

Tags: r, object, predict, supervised-learning

I am using SuperLearner R package.
I am trying to generate predicted y values for both train and test set.

After fitting a superlearner model without defining a "newX" to get predictions on the train set first so that I can compute MSE and plot predictions vs. actual Y values, I use "predict" command to predict Y values for the test set by running the following code:

```
sl.cv<-SuperLearner(Y = label, X = train, 
                 SL.library=c("SL.randomForest", "SL.glmnet", "SL.svm"),
                 method = "method.NNLS", verbose=TRUE, cvControl=list(V=10))

pred.sl.cv <- predict(sl.cv, newdata=test, onlySL = T)
```

Then, I get the following error after "predict":
"Error in object$whichScreen : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

I browsed many online sources to learn how to use "predict" after fitting a SuperLearner model, and I am doing just as what others do: That is, to put the object name of the fitted SuperLearner model (in this case, "sl.cv") followed by the new test set. I didn't even type $ operator.

Why am I getting this error message? How do I solve this problem?

Another question is: Does adding cvControl=list(V=10) as an option make any change? I think the default setting for SuperLearner model is to conduct 10-fold cross-validation. So, removing "cvControl=list(V=10)" will not change anything, right?

I would appreciate your advice. Thank you!

Comment: How does your label and train data look?  Are these matrices, vectors, ints, strings, or what are they?

Comment: The label is numeric scores and the train data is word matrix (bag of words).

Comment: The Y variable label is a vector; The X variable is a matrix. Both train and test data sets are in the same format of matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using matrices for your train and/or test data. You should use a data.frame. So change your code to the following:

```
sl.cv<-SuperLearner(Y = label, X = as.data.frame(train), 
                 SL.library=c("SL.randomForest", "SL.glmnet", "SL.svm"),
                 method = "method.NNLS", verbose=TRUE, cvControl=list(V=10))

pred.sl.cv <- predict(sl.cv, newdata=as.data.frame(test), onlySL = T)
```

Also, make sure your labels are a list.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Before splitting X into test and train data, I converted the matrix into data frame. So, both test and train sets are data frames. So, I had any problem in fitting the model. However, I will try changing labels into a list, but would it really matter...?

Comment: Notice that your error says 'object$whichScreen' so the error might arise when evaluating the "screen" algorithms in SuperLearner. I have a similar problem when using predict but my error says 'Error in object$control : $operator is invalid for atomic vectors', so it might be related to the parameter 'control'.

Comment: That's right, but I couldn't figure out how to debug this error with regards to the screening algorithms... If anybody can help me with this, that will be highly appreciated!